# Access Router in Javascript code

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I have a TypeScript component with a JS function in it. The function is called by Kendo UI so the function is executed in Javascript context, which means I can't use "this" (this returns the caller Kendo component). I want to redirect the page in this function but I rather use router.navigate* functions instead of location.href replace. Is it possible to access router instance in Javascript context?

```
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    //template: `<div #grid></div>`
    @ViewChild('grid') private grid: ElementRef;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.configureGrid();
    }

    private configureGrid() {
        let kendoGrid: kendo.ui.Grid = jQuery(this.grid.nativeElement).data("kendoGrid");
        let kendoColumn: kendo.ui.GridColumn = {};
        kendoColumn.command = { text: "My Button", click: this.myButtonCommand, className: "btn" };
        kendoGrid.columns.add(kendoColumn);
    }

    myButtonCommand(e) {
        //redirect here
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: you can use `var that = this;`  trick. https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=20AjV9HqFMaFzAW_grrgCg&gws_rd=ssl#q=javascript+this+that

Comment: Have you tried `{ text: "My Button", click: this.myButtonCommand.bind(this), className: "btn" };`?

Comment: Added sample code, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work

```
private configureGrid() {
    let kendoGrid: kendo.ui.Grid = jQuery(this.grid.nativeElement).data("kendoGrid");
    let kendoColumn: kendo.ui.GridColumn = {};
    kendoColumn.command = { text: "My Button", click: (e) => this.myButtonCommand(e), className: "btn" };
    kendoGrid.columns.add(kendoColumn);
}
```

and you should be able to just call `this.router.navigate...()` in `myButtonCommand()`

Comment: Thank you. I also want to add that your "click: this.myButtonCommand.bind(this)" method works too.